# error: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter when using inline assembly with GCC

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm tring to convert a simple assembly code of MS to use with gcc, the MS assembly I try to convert is right below. I have two `int` variables, `number` and `_return`:

```
mov eax, number
neg eax
return, eax
```

and, I have tried this:

```
asm("movl %eax, %0" :: "g" ( number));
asm("neg %eax");
asm("movl %0, %%eax" : "=g" ( return ));
```

But, the compiler gives me this error:

> main.c:17:9: error: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter

Where is the error, and, how I can fix this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it like that because you're overwriting registers without telling the compiler about it. Also, the `%` is a special character, similar to printf.

It's also better to put all the instructions in one `asm` or else the compiler *might* do something unexpected in between.

Try this instead:

```
asm("movl %%eax, %1\n\t"
    "neg %%eax\n\t"
    "movl %0, %%eax" : "=g" ( _return )  : "g" ( number) : "eax");
```

There's probably a better way, though:

```
asm("neg %0": "=a" ( _return )  : "a" ( number));
```

I don't know why you can't just do (in C):

```
_return = -number;
```

Comment: see the generate assembly, I see this: ... "mov DWORD PTR [esp+24], 0 ...  "%eax, ebx" ... "neg %eax" "movl ebx, %eax" ( the variable is wrong :( )

Comment: Your first block is backwards; AT&T syntax puts the destination last, see Aki's answer.  And if you compile with `-masm=intel`, then you shouldn't use `%` on your register names.  You also don't need to force EAX, just use `neg %0` with a `"+r"` constraint.  But yes, obviously inline asm is a terrible idea for this.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int ac,char**av)
{
    int n=ac>1?atoi(av[1]):42;
    asm ("movl %0, %%eax \n\t"
         "neg %%eax \n\t"
         "movl %%eax, %0 \n\t" : "+r" (n)::"eax");
    printf("%d\n",n);
}
```

The issues are:

- order of operands is `instr src,dst`
- %% instead of %
- no isolated lines of assembler -- the input/output/clobber list is associated to *all* of the assembler block
- '+r' to have a parameter that works as both input & output
- I doubt even MS allows using keyword "return" that way

And to make it even more efficient:

```
asm("neg %0" : "+r" (n) ::);  // works as well
```

Comment: You were on the right track with that -- I just couldn't figure out all the significant specifications from the question: it's `asm("mov %1, %0\n\t  neg %0\n\t" : "=r" (_return_value) : "r" (input):);` If you later do `return _return_value`, gcc will most likely assign `eax` as register `%0`.